# Why isn't my grid displaying properly in desktop viewport?

Tags: html, css

The grid and article elements display fine when in mobile or tablet view ports, but when expanded to a desktop view port, the grid becomes distorted.

[Mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxB4Q.jpg)

[Desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGhdW.jpg)

Style rules for mobile

```
.mobile {
    display: block;
}

.tablet-desktop {
    display: none;
}

/* Style Rules for main content */
main {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 2%;
    font-size: 1.15em;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
}

.mobile h3 {
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 8px #ccc;
}

article {
    padding: 2%;
}

article h3 {
    text-align: center;
}

article img {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

article ul {
    margin-left: 10%;
}

article:nth-of-type(2) {
    background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.3);
}
```

Style Rules for tablet

```
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    grid-gap: 20px;
}

.pic-text {
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 10px;
}

aside {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 2%;
    background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px #000;
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #b3b3b3;
    border-radius: 0 15px;
}
```

style rules for desktop

```
main {
    clear: left;
}

main h1 {
    font-size: 1.8em;
}

article h3 {
    font-size: 1.50em;
}

.pic-text {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 20px;
}

.frame {
    opacity: 0.9;
}

.frame:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    box-shadow: 8px 8px 10px #808080;
}
```

It seems the style rules that I've applied do not work for the desktop view.

Comment: I've edited the question, this is my first time using stack overflow, I apologize.

Comment: Welcome kmalice. Are you able to share your html as well so we can reproduce the error and pin point the issue?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with creating a runnable snippet in your question.